# Error while sending data to database using Flask - Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to  post data into my microsoft sql  database server but I keep on getting the following error:

Cant seem to figure out what the error may be as the error description is quite vague
I can get data from the server without any issue so it is not a server connection related issue
My python code

```
@project1.route("/addrecord", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def addcar():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("addrecord.html")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        DID = int(request.form["DID"])
        Ccode = int(request.form["Ccode"])
        TOA = request.form["TOA"]
        Debit = int(request.form["Debit"])
        Credit = int(request.form["Credit"])
        isLocked = request.form["isLocked"]
        STATUS = request.form['STATUS']
        conn = connection()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Chart_Detail (DID, Ccode, TOA, Debit, Credit, isLocked, STATUS) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", DID, Ccode, TOA, Debit, Credit, isLocked, STATUS)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return redirect('/')
```

my html code

```
<body>
<h2>Chart Details</h2>

<form action="" method = "POST">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="DID">Enter DID</label>
      <input type="NUMBER" class="form-control" DID="DID" id="DID">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Ccode">ENTER Ccode</label>
        <input type="NUMBER" class="form-control" Ccode="Ccode" id="Ccode">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="TOA">TypeOfAccount</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TOA" id="TOA">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Debit">Enter Debit Amount</label>
        <input type="NUMBER" class="form-control" name="Debit" id="Debit">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Credit">Enter Credit Amount</label>
        <input type="NUMBER" class="form-control" name="Credit" id="Credit">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="isLocked">isLocked</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="isLocked" id="isLocked">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Status">Account Status</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Status" id="Status">
    </div>
    <button type="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
  </form>
```

Comment: The error is missing from your question

Comment: action="" 
button type="btnAdd"  not sure what you did here but btnAdd is not a vaild value for the type attribute

how about action="/addrecord" and button type="submit"